# I want to start playing Poker, where do I start?

Tags: learning

Sorry I'm new asking questions, how can I start playing poker from 0?
Let me explain, I tried to investigate how to play but there are many names of plays and different types of games,
my question in particular is, where do I start?
Which is better to investigate first?
What are the bases?

Comment: Watch videos, read a beginners book. You can play at low tables for a few pennies. The problem of playing with no money is people play crazy and you don't learn anything.

Comment: I'm going to throw out a maybe not agreed upon opinion, but I'd really recommend not learning to play by playing! If you're starting fresh you have an amazing opportunity to learn the right way. Books, coaching & tutorials. I'll put an answer later or tomorrow providing more depth, but for now just wanted to comment.

Comment: @Grinch91 I think this is uncorrectly taged. I have maden an edition but I don't have reputation to do it with no aproval by a rep user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the online poker sites have play money games. Great place to start where you can just get the very basic game play, you know how the action goes, and what happens when. There you will also start to pick up how to play the game and start honing a skill set.

Alternatively just go play in a casino, that is the way we all used to learn the game. The basics, are actually quite simple and you will find you will pick it up very quickly. You will find the players are very nice and helpful with beginners, at least until you win a pot or two from them than they might get a little snarky.

Poker is a game that takes minutes to learn, and a lifetime to master. There are books available for beginners, there is a small almost pamphlet type of book that has been around for decades that can usually be found in casino gift shops or online at amazon. There is also "Poker for dummies, although it is a bit dated in some respects like with online poker advice, but it does cover the basics nicely.

As far as the type of poker game you will be playing, it will be No limit Texas Hold-em. 95% of all poker out there is Texas Hold-em. Almost all the beginner and advanced books, articles and forum posts are about Texas Hold-em. The other games, do not even worry about them for the time being. If you like poker and gain some experience you will know when it is right to start broadening your poker horizons.

You never know how it is going to go. I have a friend whom sat down in a game for the first time in 1994, and won $800 with no experience. Within a year she had won a six figure first place in a tournament. She has made her living playing ever since. (Although now retired).

Good luck Vanessa.

Answer (score 1):

You start first and foremost understanding you must have rules and those rules are never to be broken. Fully 100% of the current population of planet earth fails this concrete fact.
Having said that, you must understand money management. The money you have is the ONLY known quantity you have. The rest is all about deciphering the ambiguities of incomplete information. When you figure that out, get some chips and find a chair. Your education begins. Or not...